# group by month and year mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, date

find per customer_gender, store , month and year the total of all accounts debits in euro for the product 'Beta600' which take place before 2012

I run this query but I can't get the results I want:

```
SELECT customer_gender, product_code, month(transactions.trn_date),
year(transactions.trn_date), COUNT(trn_amount)
FROM customers, products, transactions, accounts
WHERE customer.customerid = accounts.customer_id 
AND transactions.account_id = accounts.account_id
AND accounts.product_code = products.product_code AND products.poduct_name = 'Beta600'
AND transactions.trn_date < '1/1/2012' AND accounts.account_currency = 'EUR'
GROUP BY customer_gender, product_code, month(transactions.trn_date),
year(transactions.trn_date)
```

Comment: I Use MsSQL, but as far as I am aware, you cannot use a From statement like that.
I believe you have to do it through Inner Joins.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp
Take a look at that link, it may help.

Comment: They're old style joins.  People don't recommend you use them anymore and instead use an actual JOIN but they can still be used that way.  @Thodoris - Are you sure only one table contains customer_gender and product_code?  If they're located in more than one table that you're joining you're going to have problems.

Comment: Display an example of how your table looks so we have a better understanding of the situation.

Comment: I have 5 tables:
branches, products , customers , accounts , transactions.

branches -> branch_code, branch_number_employees, branch_city.
products -> product_code, product_name.
customers -> customer_id, customer_name, customer_surname, customer_gender.
accounts -> account_id, account_currency, customer_id, branch_code, product_code.
transactions -> trn_code, trn_amount, trn_date, account_id

Comment: In your WHERE statement, should customer.customerid be customers.customerid (there is an 's' missing)?